# Trying to unzip a locked folder

Tags: password, zip, unzip

I recently downloaded a .zip archive, and i want to unzip it, so that I can run the application inside, but when I try to, it asks for a password. I am the root on my laptop, so I put in my own password, but it said that the password was wrong. Also, that is the only password that exists on my laptop (no other accounts). What should I do?

Comment: Is the zip folder encrypted with a password?

Answer (score 2):

ZIP archives can be encrypted. You will need either to know a decription password specific to the archive you downloaded or you'll need a password-guessing software `fcrackzip` that will simply try every possible password. The software is in Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

the zip file is password protected by his creator, so if you don't know it, you can't open the archive

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the .Zip File from a external source like maybe a You Tuber Gave you a link they might have put a lock on the ZIP file itself.

So you need the password to the zip file and not your computer password.